# Liquibase and Hibernate generate schema from Annotations

Tags: hibernate, annotations, liquibase

I am looking to generate SQL using liquibase based on hibernate config that is currently using JPA based annotations for mapping entities to schema.
I want to be able to do so programatically.

I see similar posts, but none with an answer/example.

Comment: What have you tried? 
It seems like you expect liquibase to read the annotations of your JPA entities. I have not used the hibernate add-on to liquibase but as far as I understand it, the liquibase-hibernate extension will just read the configuration for the database and the do a diff on the database tables (that have formerly been created by hibernate). I might be wrong on this. 
So even more: If you expect a good answer here you should show code and/or present a concrete problem that you're stuck at.